# Eureka dasboard extensibility

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

When I deploy Eureka using Spring Boot, it gives me default dashboard on 8761 port. Is it possible to extend or slightly change this console? For example I would like to see some custom properties (put into map) visible in dashboard for every service.

Comment: Potentially. The dashboard sources use freemarker. You could copy the templates and add whatever you need.

Comment: Do you know repository which contains this UI? Is it Netflix code, or Spring Cloud code? I see Spring logo on it, which is confusing.

Comment: Then it is on spring cloud Netflix